# Do I need to update constraints after I change the position of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am new to ios and have a `UIImageView` within my `viewController` that have constraints on it. I am also using `autolayout` for this app. Under a certain condition, I allow the user to move the `imageView` using the Pan Gesture. Do I need to update the constraints for that image after it is moved? Should I update the constraints after it is moved if it isn't necessary? And if yes for either of those, what is the most efficient way to update the constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move the imageView by updating its constraints, and not by changing its frame.

An easy way to do this is to position by the image view with two constraints, one that gives it an offset from the top of its superview, and one that gives it an offset from the leading edge of its superview.

Then you can create `IBOutlet`s to these constraints by <kbd>Control</kbd>-dragging from the constraints in the *Document Outline* view to your `ViewController`, then you just update the `constant` in the constraints in your Pan Gesture handler.